# making only nested col-mds responsive with bootstrap and rails

Tags: css, ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

I am using Bootstrap with Ruby on Rails. I made a row class then a sidebar with col-md-2 which is always present on the left side of the page from the header till the bottom of the page. Besides that in the same row class there is a main body with col-md-10. In the body for the users index page I made an other row and using cold-md-4 for each profile dynamically. When the browser is wide enough everything looks fine as you can see in the first pic, but when I make it just a bit tighter things get screwed up.

I wanna have only the nested columns responsive, so the sidebar never gets wider or tighter than as it is in the first pic. How could I do that? I can attach the CSS if it's required.

[[image][image]

Comment: show your code please

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want the sidebar re-sizing don't use the bootstrap row and column classes for your sidebar at all. You could simply set the width with css and stretch it to take up the height by doing something like:

```
position: absolute;
width: 200px;
top: 0px;
bottom: 0px;
left: 0px;
```

Comment: Thanks, it worked with float: left, width: 20%, min-width: 200px and I'm using height:100%. How this position:absolute, top: 0px, bottom: 0px, left: 0px combination works compared to my solution? Which one is better according to you?

Comment: I don't think either one is really better, they just respond differently to different situations. Yours for example will get bigger when the view port is wider than 1000px and it will be affected by the flow of other elements while mine will stay the same - it just depends what you want.

Comment: It turned out I couldn't pull it off after all, because of overlapping. As I made screen smaller the main body with bootstrap (I want the main body to have bootstrap as I would like to make it responsive unlike the sidebar) got on the top of the sidebar, and I couldn't find a good solution. On the other hand if I use nested bootstrap and define the outer column (sidebar) width by overwriting bootstrap code, then the main body will jump under the sidebar as I make the screen narrower. I also tried your way but it didn't work out either. I can share my current code if you want.

Answer (score 1):

My code at the moment:

```
<div id="home_loggedin">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-md-2 col-aside">
        <%= link_to "Show user", user_path(current_user) %>
        <%= link_to "Index user", users_path %>
        <%= link_to "Edit user", edit_user_profile_path(current_user) %>
      </div>
      <div class= "col-md-10 col-middle">
       <%= yield %>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The yielded code:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <h1 style="text-align:center">Users</h1>
    <ol class="user-profile-index">
      <% @users.each do |user| %>
        <div class="col-md-4">
          <li>
            <% if user.profile %>
              <% if user.profile.avatar %>
                <%= link_to user do %>
                  <%= image_tag user.profile.avatar.url(:thumb), class: 'avatar' %>
                <% end %>
              <% end %>
              <span class="user"><%= link_to user do %>
               <%= user.profile.first_name %> <%= user.profile.last_name %>
               <% end %></span>
              <span class="company"><%= user.profile.company %></span>
              <span class="job_title"><%= user.profile.job_title%></span> 
            <% end %>
          </li>
        </div>
      <% end %>
    </ol>
  </div>
</div>
```

And the css:

```
html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

#home_loggedin {
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  .container {
    height: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    .row {
      height: 100%;
      min-height: 100%;
    }
  }
}

.col-aside {
  background: $garmin-blue;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  max-width: 250px;
}

.col-middle {
  background: #fff;
  min-height: 100%;
  height: 100%;
}
```

So at the moment as I try to make the screen smaller, the main body jumps under the sidebar and the row class takes over the right side of the screen.

Comment: Two major things stand out for a start - you can't nest a bootstrap container within a container (http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container) and you are creating a div with a class of `col-md-4` for each user. This will only work if you have exactly 3 users as the bootstrap grid system requires the columns to add to 12. I would suggest looking through the bootstrap docs and looking up a few example of bootstrap with side menus to get a feel for how it should all fit together.

Comment: Check out this one for an example: http://ironsummitmedia.github.io/startbootstrap-simple-sidebar/

Comment: Thx Paul, site looks promising. My last question then. For this project what solution should I use? (I wanna keep it simple) You showed me different solutions, but which one would you stick with? Main body must be responsive, there is no question about it. When it comes to sidebar I feel, it shouldn't be, but this solution u just linked is nice. So the options: 1. No bootstrap for sidebar, but bootstrap for main body. 2. Bootstrap for sidebar (overwritten no to be responsive) and main body, and an extra nested bootstrap for main body content. 3. This toggling sidebar solution you just linked.

Comment: I would go with option 1. The reason you use bootstrap columns is because they are responsive, so if you don't want the sidebar responsive, just don't use the col-xx-xx classes. You can still use the other bootstrap styling on the sidebar of course, just not the column classes.